# Laravel 4: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Blueprint::int()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, undefined, fatal-error

I've compiled a new installation of Laravel 4 and I'm getting this error after I generate a migration and try to migrate it via artisan:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::int() in /home/casey/Sites/caseyhoffmann.me/laravel4/app/database/migrations/2013_10_22_232234_create_users_table.php on line 22
>   {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::int()","file":"/home/casey/Sites/caseyhoffmann.me/laravel4/app/database/migrations/2013_10_22_232234_create_users_table.php","line":22}}

I've tried recompiling Laravel but to no avail.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your `int`() should be replaced with `integer()` in the migrations file. Like this:

> `$table->integer('user_id');`

Comment: @AnaelFavre I agree totally. I assume this will improve over time, as Laravel matures.

Comment: agreed too, laravel errors report and stack track are in most cases unclear and not helpful at all